# I have an Issue with "simple" a IF statemente in Pine Script v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How come this line of code is note working? I'm able to plot without the If statement, but I want it to plot only when both condition are met.

Thank you for your time!

```
showMA = input.string(group="GENERAL SETTINGS", title="Moving Averages:", defval="EMA", options=["EMA", "VWAP", "Both", "None"])
show_threeEma = input.bool(group="EMA - Exponensial Moving Average", title="233-EMA", defval=true, inline="ema")

threeEma = 233
ema_space = 4 // Dash Spacing

threeEmaLength = ta.ema(close, threeEma) //233-EMA

If (showMA == "EMA" and show_threeEma or showMA == "Both" and show_threeEma == "Show")
plot(bar_index % ema_space != 0 ? threeEmaLength : na, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.silver, 25), editable=false, title="233-EMA")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `plot()` functions in local scope.

However, you can use your condition as part of your `series` argument in your `plot()` call. Just like you didi with `bar_index % ema_space != 0`.

```
can_show = (showMA == "EMA" and show_threeEma or showMA == "Both" and show_threeEma == "Show")

plot((can_show and (bar_index % ema_space != 0)) ? threeEmaLength : na, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.silver, 25), editable=false, title="233-EMA")
```